# Split one worksheet into different worksheets based on two conditions/columns (each condition in one columns)

Tags: excel, vba, multiple-columns, worksheet

I have a file that has column A with different names and column B with different departments (that person in A belongs to). Column C-E is related data to each person. I searched online and found there are some VBA codes to split one worksheet into multi sheets based on one column. I'm wondering is there a method to split worksheets that considering both columns simultaneously? Ps: the split worksheets would be named with the content of columns A and B.
Here is the code I use to split based on one column. Any suggestion is welcomed. Thanks a lot.

```
Sub parse_data()
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim vcol, i As Integer
    Dim icol As Long
    Dim myarr As Variant
    Dim title As String
    Dim titlerow As Integer

    'This macro splits data into multiple worksheets based on the variables on a column found in Excel.
    'An InputBox asks you which columns you'd like to filter by, and it just creates these worksheets.

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    vcol = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Which column would you like to filter by?", title:="Filter column", Default:="3", Type:=1)
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
    title = "A1"
    titlerow = ws.Range(title).Cells(1).Row
    icol = ws.Columns.Count
    ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"
    For i = 2 To lr
        On Error Resume Next
        If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
            ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
        End If
    Next

    myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
    ws.Columns(icol).Clear

    For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
        ws.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
        If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
            Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
        Else
            Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        End If
        ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
        'Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
    Next

    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    ws.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: If col A is a name and col B is department, then you want to create a sheet for every person?? What data would go to every sheet?

Comment: sorry I didn't state it clearly. Col A has names but not unique, each person would have multiple rows of data (stored randomly). Data into each sheet would be all the entries (row) of a person along with department plus info from col C to E

Comment: Why not add a helper column which concatenates A and B then use that column with the code above?

Comment: Thank you SJR, that's a great suggestion, I will try it out.

Comment: Btw there are easier ways to get a list of unique values than looping through everything.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, is it possible to share a link regarding the easier method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dictionaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object) are useful for creating lists of unique values.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CreateDeptPerson()

    Const RNG_HEADER = "A1:E1"
    Const START_ROW = 2 ' row 1 header

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, arHeader As Variant
    Dim iRow As Long, iLastRow As Long, i As Long, n As Integer

    Dim dict As Object, key As String
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    ' add existing sheets to dictionary
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    For Each ws In wb.Sheets
        iRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count + ws.UsedRange.Row ' last row +1
        dict.Add ws.Name, iRow
    Next

    ' extent of  data
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") ' change to name of data sheet
    iLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    arHeader = ws.Range(RNG_HEADER).Value2
    
    ' scan down column A
    For iRow = START_ROW To iLastRow
        'sheet name as "dept name"
        key = Trim(ws.Cells(iRow, "B")) & " " & Trim(ws.Cells(iRow, "A"))

        ' add a sheet if not in dictionary
        If Not dict.exists(key) Then
           With wb.Sheets.Add(after:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
               .Name = key
               .Range(RNG_HEADER) = arHeader
           End With
           ' add name to dictionary
           dict.Add key, 2
           n = n + 1
        End If

        ' copy row to the sheet named key
        i = dict(key)
        ws.Cells(iRow, 1).EntireRow.Copy wb.Sheets(key).Cells(i, 1)
        dict(key) = i + 1 'move down for next record
    Next
    MsgBox n & " Sheets Created"

End Sub
```